# Is there any better way than manually writing this move constructor?

Tags: c++

In the current example:

```
struct MYFOO
{
private:
    MYFOO() { }
    MYFOO(const MYFOO&) = delete;
    MYFOO(MYFOO&& other) = default;

    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e; 
    int f;
    VkImage image = VK_NULL_HANDLE;


};
```

The default move constructor "ALMOST" does the right job, except that if moving an object the other's VkImage needs to be set to VK_NULL_HANDLE. If I write the move constructor manually assigning each member, not only is it tedious (that's the least of the potential problems), but it's also really error prone in that if I add another member it won't be moved correctly. How should I handle this?

Comment: Why is a duplicated `VkImage` bad? Should the destructor be doing something about the `image` member?

Comment: Would creating a wrapper around `VkImage` that "fixes" its move semantics be an option?

Comment: [Or you could just use the official C++ Vulkan bindings with RAII types.](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp)

Answer (score 2):

Make that class a subclass

```
struct MYIMAGE {
    MYIMAGE() = default;
    MYIMAGE(MYIMAGE&& other) noexcept : image(other.image) {
        other.image = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    }
    VkImage image = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
};

struct MYFOO : MYIMAGE
{
private:
    MYFOO() { }
    MYFOO(const MYFOO&) = delete;
    MYFOO(MYFOO&& other) = default;

    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e; 
    int f;
};
```

Comment: `MYIMAGE` can still be a member. No need of inheritance.

Comment: @Jarod42, yes, `MYIMAGE` can be extended with converting and assignment operators and used as a `VkImage` wrapper.

Comment: Updated the answer, I read the question first time incorrectly, other's image should have been reset